# When is a generator not a generator? Why does calling my function with yield not return a generator object sometimes

Tags: python, generator

I have a function `(f)` with a `yield`. I have a list `(E)`. 
 
If I try `E += f()` then `f()` doesn't return a generator object, but instead runs the function, which throws an exception because some global variables aren't ready. 

To forestall any comments, I know `E += f()` is wrong, but it provides an example for my question. If I do the right thing `E += [f()]` or `E.append(f())` then f() returns a generator object and the code of `f()` is not evaluated till the generator object's `next` method is called. 
My question is, why is `f()` being evaluated in the wrong situation at all, and why instead is the exception raised not something along the lines of "function object not iterable".

Comment: Have you considered making a class with a `__call__` method and instantiating it? Also, why are your generators depending on globals?

Comment: Err, not sure I can fit this all in a comment. My Phd research is in modeling systems with rule replacement, i.e. self modifying systems. This means the rules (functions) randomly get removed from the symbol table, and collectively must recreate and `exec` function definitions to replace lost functionality. Ideally, functionality would never be entirely lost, as each rule would have many copies. So to answer your first question, it's mostly a semantic thing, but rules should be functions and not objects; I know in python everything is an object...

Comment: but I'm just playing around in python, and will probably implement the model in something else eventually. The global the generators depend on is the symbol table (or in the current implementation a huge list of functions/strings/lists)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the expression `f()` calls `f`, and `E += f()` will run the generator until its end and append the values it generates to `E`. It's not "wrong" at all, but it does require a fully working `f` that yields a finite number of values:

```
>>> E = [1,2,3]
>>> def f():
...  yield 4
...  yield 5
...
>>> E += f()
>>> E
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

By contrast, `E += [f()]` will call `f`, but then stops before the first line of the code because then the interpreter has a complete enough object, namely the generator object, to store in the single-element list `[f()]`. Only later, when you request more elements from `E[-1]`, will code up to the first `yield` run and the exception be raised.

Comment: I thought that calling f would yield a generator object, not evaluate the code of f (so to speak). What I don't understand (if your explanation is correct) is why `E += [f()]` doesn't throw an exception too, because the NameError exception should be thrown before the yield is encountered.

Comment: @sirlark, larsmans has his description slightly wrong. When you call f() the generator is created but none of it actually executes until you try to get a value from it. Only when you try to get the first value does it execute as far as the first `yield`.

Comment: @Duncan, thanks for the clarification, that's pretty much what I thought

Comment: @larsmans, the 'wrong' aspect here is that I don't want to add the output of the generator to the list, I want to add multiples copies of the generator to the list, so I knew it wouldn't do what I wanted. I should have explained that better, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, so as I was typing that last line of the question I think I figured this out.

`E += f()` is list concatenation, which implies the result of f() must be iterable, and furthermore, that iterator is evaluated as part of of the concatenation, meaning f().next is called

`E += [f()]` wraps the generator object in a and iterable object (a list) and it is this outer list that is evaluated

`E.append(f())` is not concatenation of lists, but rather in place addition of an element (whose iterable properties, if any, are ignored), so the generator object never gets evaluated